# Ajax and JSON arrays

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to use JSON data format together with jQuery and, well, it would be surprising if it worked.

In my remoteServiceEngine.php, I have something like this:

```
$jResponse[0] = json_encode(array("jAction" => "add", "jObject" => "listCountries", "jBody" => "test"));
$json_data = json_encode(array("jRequestState" => $jRequestState, "jMessage" => $jMessage, "jResponse" => $jResponse));
echo $json_data;
```

And this is how it is handled in JS:

```
 success: function(remoteResponse){
        switch(remoteResponse.jRequestState) {
            case 0:
                $("#removeServiceMessage").fadeIn(2000).html('<div class="remoteError">'+remoteResponse.jMessage+'</div>').fadeOut(2000);
            break;

            case 1:
                $("#removeServiceMessage").fadeIn(2000).html('<div class="remoteSuccess"><B>Success:</B> '+remoteResponse.jMessage+'</div>').fadeOut(2000);
                for (i = 0; i < remoteResponse.jResponse.length; i++) {
                    switch(remoteResponse.jResponse[i].jAction) {
                        case "add":
                            $("#"+remoteResponse.jResponse[i].jObject).fadeIn(1000).append(remoteResponse.jResponse[i].jBody);
                        break;

                        case "remove":
                            $("#"+remoteResponse.jResponse[i].jObject).fadeOut(1000);
                        break;

                        case "update":
                            $("#"+remoteResponse.jResponse[i].jObject).fadeIn(1000).html(remoteResponse.jResponse[i].jBody);
                        break;

                        default:
                            alert(remoteResponse.jResponse[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            break;
        }
    }
```

The whole problem is that I cannot access successful content. With $jRequestState = 1 and the forementioned $jResponse[0], switch goes directly onto default and this is the output I get:

```
{"jAction":"add","jObject":"listCountries","jBody":"test"}
```

but I cannot figure out how to access these elements. I tried it with:

```
alert(remoteResponse.jResponse[i]['jAction']);
```

and

```
alert(remoteResponse.jResponse[i][0]); //yeah, that's kinda stupid solution, but well...
```

Since I've never used JSON with jQuery, I can't figure out how to deal with that. Help, anybody?

Comment: You're encoding `$jResponse[0]` as JSON twice in PHP.

Comment: you may want to look at [knockout](http://http://knockoutjs.com/) because this works to minify your jQuery usage by dealing with only the data and binding it to the appropriate controls, if you're interested then message back and I'll post a knockout answer for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Like adeneo said in the comment you jsonencode twice. Your php code should look like:

```
$jResponse[0] = array("jAction" => "add", "jObject" => "listCountries", "jBody" => "test");
$json_data = json_encode(array("jRequestState" => $jRequestState, "jMessage" => $jMessage, "jResponse" => $jResponse));
echo $json_data;
```